# como instalar las dependencias para utilizar las bibliotecas de clases .Net Core en visual studio 2022?

Tags: visual-studio

hola buenas tengo una duda, pasa que estoy haciendo un curso de udemy sobre un proyecto en ASP.NET con MVC pero cuando el profe va a crear un nuevo proyecto y selecciona Bibilioteca de clases .Net Core ami no me aparece y nose que me hace falta instalar en mi visual studio 2022.

les dejo un par de imagenes de lo que les comento.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esto son un par de imagenes que descarge de youtube (no es mi curso de udemy)

otra cosa que me llama la atencion es esto (esto no es mi visual studio)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

veo en este video que abajo abajo , en el video instalan algo que dice desarrollo multiplaforma de .net core, nose si es por no instalar ese que no me deja usar esa biblioteca de clases de .net core ?.

si es asi nose como hacer porque ami no me sale esa opcion en mi visual studio 2022

adjunto scriem de vi visual studio al buscar dicha biblioteca.

como lo notaran no aparece

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el curso

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Con [Desarrollo de ASP.NET y Web](https://ibb.co/PFs7vhd) debería bastar para lo que quieres hacer.

Comment: vieras que no ya lo tengo instalado pero luego cuando quiero agregar esa libreria de clases a un proyecto no me aparece

Comment: [Edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/537118/edit) y comparte una foto de lo que te sale al "crear proyecto" para evaluar tu problema específico. Lo que compartes son solamente capturas de videos de youtube que poco ayudan a saber que pasa. ¿No tiene el curso de udemy una sección de instalación?

Comment: voy a compartir imagen de lo que me sale cuando pongo biblioteca de clases .net core

Comment: vieras que el profe simplemente instala todo en el curso, y son como 60 gb

Comment: entonces no puedo saber realmente que me faltara instalar, porque en el curso el profe instala absolutamente todo y son como 60gb

Comment: Es gracioso, porque [lo tienes a la izquierda](https://ibb.co/wgm677f) XD, lo cual significa que lo has usado antes y todo. Por otro lado. Escribe sólo `core` en el cuadro de búsqueda, no pongas tanto texto. En el video de youtube que tu misma pones solo escriben `core`.

Comment: lo que yo busco se llama Bibilioteca de clases .Net Core

Comment: lo que hay a la izquierda es Bibilioteca de clases .Net Framework

Answer (score 1):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
De esta manera creas lo que necesitas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Explica además tu respuesta _como texto_. [No todos pueden ver las imágenes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976). Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.